# midi setup axiom25 on nuendo 4

Tags: midi, setup, nuendo4, steinberg

hzt guys, just a question, I've recently purchased an axiom25 midi controller, nuendo 4 recognizes it and there is an input when i press a key on the controller why am i not hearing anything also do i have have to download something from the steinberg site?

thanks and happy easter

Answer (score 1):

@JM V It depends on how you set this up. You have to have a midi track and then you have to assign a controller to that track. You will see the midi track with midi data when you press a key. From what I am reading is that you are half way there. You have to tell the midi controller (Axiom) what you want it to play. When you look at the midi track you should see a place to assign it a sound like the harmony (VST instruments) (a synth, which is like a keyboard, which is what gives the sounds you want. Then when you can pick the patch you want. I hope this makes sense to you. If not let me know and I can try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get mine to work. I found nothing of the sort on the net so I hope this helps even if it's waaaaaay late. Make sure you have the latest drivers for your axiom first, found here:

http://m-audio.com/index.php?do=support&tab=driver

In Nuendo 4 (or any Steinberg based audio software I assume)
 - right click on any track
 - add track
 - add an instrument track
 - select synth -> monologue (choose any synth you have/like)
 - highlight/select the new instrument track in your list
 - on the left hand side of your window, you will see a list, double click on the very first object on the list (should be the name of your instrument track), it will open a submenu if it wasn't already open
 - Make sure your Input Routing is "All MIDI Inputs" and not "Not connected" and make sure your synth is also selected right under that 
 - finally, to hear your midi controller (and this is what pissed me off when I figured out) simply click on the "record" button on the instrument track itself.
 - Push a key to hear a sound
 - Punch yourself if you did every step except push the record button (optional)

Hope this helps!